# Google Stackdriver Grafana integration

Tags: visibility, grafana, metrics, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

This is a question related to Stackdriver and Grafana integration.

I have created a log based metrics, metrics type is **Distribution** not Counter. I want o make that available in Grafana. I have added stackdriver as datasource, but i am not able to see metrics in grafana.

I did not see enough docs around it online..Anyone has done it before ?

Comment: Did you get this working? Have you been able to access any Stackdriver metrics? The content at the following link looks reasonable detailed, is this what you're using? https://grafana.com/docs/v5.3/features/datasources/stackdriver/

Comment: I just tried this for myself and it appears to work. Let me know whether that documentation link helps you.

Comment: This doc helped me to setup stackdriver as a datasource in grafana, but does not says anything about how we can import log based metrics that we created in stackdriver..

Comment: I can see metrics names  in the list in grafana..but it does not render anything..when i look at the api calls made to stackdriver through chrome console  i can see data coming as null

Comment: I assume if you use the Stackdriver Console directly, you see metric data against these log metrics for the same time period.

Comment: What was the prefix of your service account? Curiously (!?) when I created a service account named `grafana`, I received 403s. So I created a different service account `robot-xxx` and it worked. I will try deleting and recreating the service accounts but that would be a curious bug.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback. Yes i am able to create graphs in stackdriver. 

My service account name does not contains grafana. In fact i tried from two different account.